# Navigating between Silverlight islands causes exceptions in Firefox 9+ and Chrome, but not IE 9

Tags: silverlight, firefox, google-chrome, wcf-data-services

I have a few Silverlight applications in my website. Each are on their own page and do not interact with each other. I'm using Silverlight 5 and WCF Data Services for data access.
IE has been working great, but when I switch between the two while the first one is in the middle of getting data from the WCF Data Service (or we also have a .aspx page that is serving up xml in the code behind and it happens there as well).

It's throwing some seemingly random exceptions and I'm not sure how to handle them. Any ideas on how to avoid these, or cancel calls when the url changes in FF?

Chrome reports my WCF Data Service webget request as canceled and undefined. [image]

Here's a list of what I've captured so far:

{System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to Invoke: callOpen.
   at System.Windows.Browser.ScriptObject.Invoke(String name, Object[] args)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ScriptObjectUtility.CallOpen(ScriptObject request, String method, String uri)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ScriptXmlHttpRequest.Open(String uri, String method, Action readyStateChangeCallback)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebRequest.InvokeRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.InvokeAsync(Func`3 asyncAction, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.BeginExecute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.BeginExecute(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
.....

### HttpWebResponse.NormalizeResponseStatus....

{System.InvalidOperationException: get_BrowserInformation failed.
   at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.get_BrowserInformationInternal()

### at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.get_BrowserInformation()

{System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Http.WebException: Internal error at 'HttpWebResponse.NormalizeResponseStatus'.
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebResponse.NormalizeResponseStatus(Int32& statusCodeParam)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebResponse..ctor(XHRHttpWebRequest request, Int32 statusCode, String responseHeaders)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebRequest.CreateResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at DataService.<>c__DisplayClass6`1.b__1(IAsyncResult iar)}

**Firebug is showing:**

Firebug:
   attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
   Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]
[Break On This Error]
...ge to get source for: http://localhost/Visiconn/Pages/Administration/ViewDisplay...

[System.Data.Services.Http.WebException] = {System.Data.Services.Http.WebException: Internal error at 'ScriptXmlHttpRequest.CreateNativeRequest'.
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ScriptXmlHttpRequest.CreateNativeRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.Http.XHRHttpWebRequest.InvokeRequest()
   at Syst...